# Add my application intent to menu in contact photo dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

Is that possible to add my application intent into the menu of photo sources in contacts? There are gallery and camera now but I want my application to provide a source image for the contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is dependent upon the implementation of "contacts". Not all phones use the same application and not all will have the same implementation.

Your application can have an activity that advertises that it supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with a MIME type pattern of `image/*`, and that may get picked up by the Contacts app. It will be called with `startActivityForResult()`. Normally, you would use `setResult()` return a `content://` `Uri` pointing to the photo, but it appears that the AOSP Contacts app is expecting a `Bitmap` object in a `data` extra. So, you'll have to experiment.